# mysql - delete from multiple tables using a union

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is it possible to delete from multiple tables using a `UNION`? The column field I have in each table is the same and has the same value. Here's the query I currently have (error due to ambiguity).

```
DELETE
    i,
    l,
    dl
FROM
    items i,
    lists l,
    display_lists dl
WHERE
    account_id = ?
    AND
    owner_id = ?
```

Comment: Unless you only want to delete from any table only if a value exists in all 3 tables then I would just use 3 deletes but your question does not make clear why you would want to join or union all tables and delete.

Comment: @P.Salmon I guess I just want to be a little bit lazy and not have to repeat myself.